# Woocommerce, cart and multiples

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shopping-cart, items

I have a client asking for a feature in Woocommerce:

He sells different kinds of products and one of them is wine.
He would like to display the price per item but to only sell them by 6, 12, 18 etc...

So, he would like, when the cart is populated, to see by default 6 items (for the wine) and one item for any other item.
And if the user wants more, by incrementing the value, it will not display 7 wines but 12, etc...

This is specific to wine but he also wants to be able to sell other things by groups of 2, 3, 4 etc...

Is there a plugin or an idea to be able to do so for any item he wants?

I know Google is my friend but I don't even know how to formulate this requirement within Google to find an answer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`woocommerce_quantity_input()`](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_quantity_input.html#913) function. Within you will see filters for the "minimum", "maximum", and "step" values. You would want to change the step value. You can set up the conditional logical however you'd like, but if you intend to give control to your client you will probably want to make the "step" a custom field/post meta.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_step', 'so_27357765_change_step', 10, 2 );
function so_27357765_change_step( $step, $product ){
   if( $new_step = get_post_meta( $product->id, '_product_step', true ) ){
      $step = intval( $new_step );
   }
   return $step;
}
```